# Write and load JSON string with data.table

Tags: r, json, data.table

I tried to save JSON string to CSV with `fwrite`. But I can't load it back with `fread`.

**Question: What the quotes settings should I use here?**

```r
library(data.table)
library(jsonlite)

r <- list(a = "text")
d <- data.table(
  a = toJSON(r, auto_unbox = TRUE)
)

tmp <- tempfile()
fwrite(d, tmp, quote = TRUE, qmethod = "escape")
fromJSON(fread(tmp)[["a"]][1])
```

Code above produce error:

```r
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                      {\"a\":\"text\"}
                     (right here) ------^
```

Comment: Why do you want to save JSON as csv and not as JSON ?

Comment: JSON fetched from the PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution with `qmethod = "double"` for the current version (1.12.3):

```r
library(data.table)
library(jsonlite)

r <- list(a = "text")
d <- data.table(
  a = toJSON(r, auto_unbox = TRUE)
)

tmp <- tempfile()
fwrite(d, tmp, quote = TRUE, qmethod = "double")
fromJSON(gsub("\"\"", "\"", fread(tmp)[["a"]], fixed = TRUE)[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can't.

The docs for `fread()` clearly state that slash-escaped quotes should be handled in quoted columns:

> Unescaped quotes may be present in a quoted field, e.g., ...,2,"Joe, "Bloggs"",3.14,..., as well as escaped quotes, e.g., ...,2,"Joe \",Bloggs\"",3.14,....

If this were the case, the method you are using should work. In fact, a search on the data.table GitHub repository reveals [an open issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1109) about this. In the mean time, you'll need to either fix the data after `fread()`, or use some other function to read the data.